# OpenGL version and programming

Tags: c++, opengl, version

I am using VS2010 and freeGlut2.8.1, it seems that the openGL version on computer is 4, (also I am new to openGL) I have kept reading the many of the openGL features of earlier version are no longer used in recent version and the pipeline has changed ... , how come I am coding, using the tutorials on openGL red book which is for version 1 and every thing is working ok???

Comment: compatibility, if you request a core profile the glBegin and glEnd won't work any more and you will need to use shaders

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be using a deprecated version of OpenGL while serious about programming on it. Since glut is old and its design rather rusty, I suggest using a recent windowing API that allows you to program with OpenGL 3.3+. Examples of such windowing APIs include SDL, SFML, GLFW to name a few. Also, the red book on OpenGL although is useful in understanding how OpenGL works doesn't implement it in the most up-to-date manner. There are plenty of other books out there like OpenGL SuperBible or Shader Cookbook that can get you started.

Comment: FreeGLUT has excellent support for modern OpenGL. Just saying.

Comment: Indeed, it does; but its functionality is terrible!

Comment: Except on OS X. For whatever reason, FreeGLUT has no native Cocoa codepath (NSOpenGL). It requires an X server even on OS X, and the GLX server Apple (used to) ship was limited to OpenGL 2.1. _Best to avoid FreeGLUT if you intend to port your modern GL software to OS X._

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at [modern OpenGL tutorials](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/)

IMHO using glbegin / glend pairs allows one to see the big picture. But their usage is *never* encouraged any more.